# Duplicate question results in question ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

This is more of a statement than a discussion. I've had some questions in the past that weren't received well, which is fine. I learned my lesson, and try to make my questions clearer and do my homework by searching Stack Overflow, general Google searches, and different methods of solving the problem before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Which in general means, that I'm very careful before asking a question, and generally now use more time on moderating what I can at my level and trying to help others. Then when I do ask a question, I try to make it as clear as possible, and enter all info on what I've tried, and research I've made.

Today, I asked a question which already had been asked. This did not show up in my searches on Stack Overflow, or Google - even though I thought my searches were pretty direct. But of course, my searches might not have been as direct as they could, but still I didn't find it.

**So:**
My question then gets closed as a duplicate, which is fine, since it was answered elsewhere. But this resulted in a question ban. I realise it is not solely based on this **one** question, but I'm still amazed that the question ban will be triggered by an unintentional duplicate question - which now means I can't ask questions for another 6 month.

I think that's just wrong.

Comment: *"which now means I cant ask questions for another 6 month."* - That generally means *you never got out of the question ban in the first place*, the ban allows you to ask a question every 6 months, it doesn't guarantee that the question you ask will get you out of the ban

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing I dont know for sure if its 6 month, but thats just what it says in the help center. So this in generel means, that the question has be pretty well received before lifting the ban, and if its just the smallest error (like a duplicate question), then it is reinstated. I dont get how that is the best way of handling situations like that.

Comment: That's why we encourage users to not only improve going forward, but also to fix their old posts (deleted posts included) by editing. The further away you can get from being on the edge of a ban the better

Comment: Your last undeleted question was asked almost a year ago.  Unless you asked something within the last 6 months that go deleted, I'd guess that the question you asked today was your free question you got at the 6 month mark.  It is unlikely you were actually unbanned, which means you still need to try to fix your old questions as best as possible to get more upvotes and allow you to ask questions again without waiting 6 months

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing Yes, I also read that in the help center. At that point I read that, I figured I would go back and edit them. But it is only possible to see recently deleted questions - which then is too late, because I got the ban some time after I deleted some of the questions

Comment: @Patrick If you ask nicely I'm sure that a moderator will provide you links to your older deleted questions :)

Comment: Usually with these kind of posts a moderator will come along and post a list of older deleted questions.

Comment: @NickAthePopcornKing Ah, I see. I didnt know that what possible. I would be very happy if a kind soul would assist me with the possiblity :) But then if I now realise that some of them are just stupid question I asked? Ive learned a thing or two over the last couple of years, and I have an idea that most of those questions are pretty old - also just based on the ban I've had.

Comment: @Patrick Even if it is stupid question it can be improved. Questions that are really hard to fix (or impossible) are off topic ones (asking for books, libraries, naming questions, opinion based)

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/55583242) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/47332605) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/47259792) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/42683041) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/42603042) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/41818696) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/41783010) [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/41091329))

Comment: I don't understand how this person was banned in the first place. They have decent reputation and some decently upvoted questions. Sure there must be some deleted questions that were downvoted, but unless that number (of deleted posts) is not shocking teh ban should be lifted.

Comment: @kemicofa A post-ban **can't** be lifted manually. It's wholly automatic.

Comment: Now that we have the deleted questions, there are only 8 and none of them have more than a -2. This is not a shocker.

Comment: @yivi "can't".. I'm sure they could if they wanted..

Comment: @kemicofa They could change the system. But it works this way by design. And changes would have many side effects, and plenty additional work for the moderators.

Comment: @kemicofa *"and none of them have more than a -2"* because OP already deleted most of their questions after a few minutes, so yes it is no shocker it couldn't receive more downvotes. But it is certainly no argument _in favor_ of the OP either.

Comment: @Tom I don't see any exact information as to when a question was deleted so saying "after a few minutes" is not accurate. Going through the deleted questions and comparing the date of the comments and answers it can be said that it's more than a *few minutes* where one even goes up to 20+ minutes. That being said, the most recent deleted question is 6 months ago and previously over one year ago. I would *tend* to be in favor.

Comment: @kemicofa The "deleted" banner tells you when the question was deleted. You can even hover any date with your mouse to get an exact timestamp including seconds. So pretending you can't see that information is ... let's call it strange.

Comment: @Tom I'm glad you pointed it out since it's clearly not visible to know a timestamp exists when hovering. Knowing this does not change my point in the least. *Clearly* over a "few minutes". I rest my case.

Comment: Obviously the problem is that not everybody is in agreement on what "a few" constitute. I propose we constitute a committee, namely the "Committee of the Few", to try to define how this expression should be interpreted in various contexts. This committee should have more than a few members, of course... I'll see myself out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You weren't "re-banned" because your question was marked as a dupe.

What happened was that the question you asked didn't get enough of a good reception to get you **out** of the ban.

The post-ban mechanics gives you a new chance of posting a new question or answer (depending on the ban) each six months. If that post doesn't get a very hot reception, you get back to wait until your next opportunity.

But if that post gets enough upvotes, you may eventually dig yourself out of the ban.

Since a question every 6 months might not be enough to compensate for a very poor question record a user might have, it's always good to try to edit and improve **old** questions.

And deleted questions also count, so you can ask a moderator for links to your old deleted questions with score <= 0 to try to improve those as well (if it's possible at all), before undeleting them.

You can do that either by asking a question on meta, or by raising a custom moderator flag on any of your posts.